# Rails Form Saving the Wrong Date via `datetime_select`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a perplexing situation with the edit view of a form on my app.  In some (but not all) instances, the `event_date` being saved in the database is different than what is put into the `f.datetime_select` field on the form.  For example, if I select "November 5" and hit submit and check my console, the `event_date` reads "November 11".  I only have this issue with *some* of the instances, and only with the `edit` view (not the `new` view).

My form code from my `reminders#edit` (which is the same as my `reminders#new`, for the record) is as follows:

```
<%= form_for @reminder do |f| %>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="field col-xs-7 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.label "Thing to Remember" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.label "Date" %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :event_date, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field manly-radios col-xs-6">
        <%= f.label "Repeat Event?" %><br>
        <%= f.radio_button :repeating, "None" %>
        <%= f.label :repeating, "No Repeat", value: "None"  %><br>
        <%= f.radio_button :repeating, "Weekly" %>
        <%= f.label :repeating, "Weekly", value: "Weekly"  %><br>
        <%= f.radio_button :repeating, "Monthly" %>
        <%= f.label :repeating, "Monthly", value: "Monthly"  %><br>
        <%= f.radio_button :repeating, "Yearly" %>
        <%= f.label :repeating, "Yearly", value: "Yearly"  %><br>
      </div>

      <div class="field col-xs-6">
        <%= f.check_box :gift %>
        <%= f.label "Gift required" %><br>
        <%= f.check_box :gift_help %>
        <%= f.label "Help me find a gift" %><br>
        <%= f.check_box :reminder %>
        <%= f.label "Please remind me" %>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- row -->

    <div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 25px">
      <%= f.submit "Remind Me", class: "hvr-grow btn btn-manly" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My `reminders_controller.rb` method for `edit` is like this:

```
  def edit
    @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
    @reminder.save
    render layout: 'nofooter'
  end
```

With these strong parameters:

```
private

  def reminder_params
    params.require(:reminder).permit(:name, :user, :event_date, :mail_date, :occasion_type, :reminder, :repeating, :gift, :gift_help)
  end
```

And here's my `reminder.rb` model:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :create_mail_date
  after_save :send_reminder_emails
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def create_mail_date
    @schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(self.event_date)
    case self.repeating
    when "Weekly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.weekly
        )
    when "Monthly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.monthly.day_of_month(self.event_date.mon)
        )
    when "Yearly"
        @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
            IceCube::Rule.yearly.day_of_year(self.event_date.yday)
        )
    end
    if self.repeating
        self.event_date = @schedule.next_occurrence(Time.current)
    end
    self.mail_date = self.event_date  - 7.days
  end

  private

  def send_reminder_emails
      if self.reminder
       RemainderMailerJob.set(wait_until: self.mail_date).perform_later(user, remainder)
         #ReminderMailer.delay(run_at: self.mail_date).reminder_send(self.user, self)
         self.create_mail_date
     end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :send_reminder_emails

end
```

Can anyone see what is causing this weird behavior?

Comment: did you tried to create an event with no repeating ??

Comment: Are all the instances present on the same server? If the instances with the wrong date are on a different server then we can check for that server's date and time.

Comment: @Bandi, the error only happens with repeating events.  From what I can tell, it only happens on monthly and yearly repeating events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monthly method of calculating the next date:

```
when "Monthly"
    @schedule.add_recurrence_rule(
        IceCube::Rule.monthly.day_of_month(self.event_date.mon)
    )
```

Referenced `self.event_date.mon` referring to the number of the month instead of `self.event_date.day` referring to the day of the month.  Therefore things in November were given a day number of 11, etc.